# Posting JSON string using dojo.xhrPost

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, dojo

I am having an issue trying to post a JSON string using `dojo.xhrPost` to a Zend Framework Controller.

When I post the string to the server I get no data being sent.  I've even tried just sending "A Test string", even that is not being sent.

I've done a var dump to see the contents of the request but clear as day, there is no parameter or data of what I am posting.  My code looks like this:

```
var jsonStr = dojo.toJson(values);
var xhrArgs = ({
        url:"/dojo/savedetails/",
        postData: jsonStr,
        handleAs: "text",               
        load: function(data){

            if(data == 'success'){

                //success code
               dojo.byId('edit_alert').innerHTML = '<div class="info">Your changes have been saved</div>'

            }else{

                dojo.byId('edit_alert').innerHTML = '<div class="error">We were unable to save your changes please try again.</div>';
            }

        }           

    });

    //we now post the data to the server for processing.
    var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

The contents of my `var_dump($this->_request)` is:

```
object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http)#118 (14) { ["_paramSources":protected]=>  
array(2) { [0]=>  string(4) "_GET" [1]=>  string(5) "_POST" } ["_requestUri":protected]=>  string(25) "/dojo/savedetails/" 
["_baseUrl":protected]=>  string(0) "" ["_basePath":protected]=>  NULL ["_pathInfo":protected]=>  string(25) "/dojo/savedetails/" ["_params":protected]=>
array(3) { ["controller"]=>  string(4) "dojo" ["action"]=>  string(18) "savedetails" ["module"]=>  string(7) "default" } ["_aliases":protected]=>  array(0)
{ } ["_dispatched":protected]=>  bool(true) ["_module":protected]=>  string(7) "default" ["_moduleKey":protected]=>  string(6) "module" 
["_controller":protected]=>  string(4) "dojo" ["_controllerKey":protected]=>  string(10) "controller" ["_action":protected]=>  
string(18) "savedetails" ["_actionKey":protected]=>  string(6) "action" }
```

I hope that I am missing something simple however I've been following the documentation on dojotoolkit.org, and from their examples this should work.

I'm Using Dojo 1.3 and Zend Framework 1.9 if that helps.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `postData` to pass in the content, you need to use `dojo.rawXhrPost` instead of `dojo.xhrPost`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `content` instead of `postData`. Also, load up Firebug (firefox), Developer Tools (chrome/IE), or Fiddler and see what the actual outgoing HTTP request looks like.